# System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path denied in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I have published an App in the store and there is this weird behavior. Some users are unable to use the app as it is giving an exception

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "//path//filename" denied.
```

The stack trace is below.

```
1 at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

2 at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)

3 at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
```

The code which does this is

```
var filePath = String.Format(".\\TestDataSet\\{0}", "TestJson");

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
        {
            return;
        }

        File.Delete(filePath);

        using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                await writer.WriteAsync(content);
            }
        }
```

The App is up and running in 75% of devices. 25% of users are facing this issue.

Does it have something to do with the Windows Phone update in some of the devices ? Or the user can set device specific / app specific permissions ?

Comment: Probably would need the whole async function.  Looks like you're trying to delete a directory and not a file.  Or you forgot to close the file before trying to delete it.

Comment: Thats the whole async method with "content" being a parameter to the method.

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware Thank u. The issue had nothing to do with store account. When we were testing we didnt identified this issue. But when we focused our testing to reproduce this particular issue we found that it had to do with threads. Before a thread had finished deleting a file another thread would have started to write content on it. I removed the file write and delete operations and made necessary changes to solve the issue.